# How to remove "G1R" of the row value: "NG1R" in R programming

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

How to remove if row values:"G1R or G2R.. G3R...etc" from the row value: "NG1R" and replace the "N" value to the empty cell of the same row using regular expressions. How to do it without hardcoding of any column names, row names, and row values in R programming. Please check my expected output below.

**Code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:5), 
  emp_name = c("M3737","M3738","M3739", "NG1R M3740","M3741"),
  realvalues=c("N", "N", "N", "", "N"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(emp.data)
```

**output:**

```
emp_id   emp_name      real_values salary
1      1      M3737          N     623.30
2      2      M3738          N     515.20
3      3      M3739          N     611.00
4      4   NG1R M3740              729.00
5      5      M3741          N     843.25
```

**Expected output:**

```
emp_id   emp_name      real values salary
1      1      M3737          N     623.30
2      2      M3738          N     515.20
3      3      M3739          N     611.00
4      4      M3740          N     729.00
5      5      M3741          N     843.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
transform(
  replace(emp.data, emp.data == "", NA_character_),
  realvalues = ifelse(
    is.na(realvalues) & grepl("^N\\w+\\s+", emp_name),
    "N",
    realvalues
  ),
  emp_name = gsub("^N\\w+\\s+", "", emp_name)
)
```

Note mentioning vec names (note this may have unintended consequences and I wouldn't recommend doing this if your data differs from the sample provided):

```
data.frame(Map(function(x){
  if(is.character(x)){
      gsub("^N\\w+\\s+", "", na.omit(x)[cumsum(!is.na(x))])
    } else{x}
  }, replace(emp.data, emp.data == "", NA_character_)))
```

Comment: how to it without even mentioning column name "emp_name"

Comment: @kumar you are revaluing the emp_name vector so unless you want to use column indices then this is how you do it. Generally you upvote and accept an answer if it does what you desire.

Comment: the code looks like you have hardcoded the "emp_name" and "realvalues" how to do it without mentioning these names

Comment: @kumar you obviously don't understand what "hardcoded" means, and good Stack Overflow etiquette is to upvote and / or accept solutions that answer your original post, not a revision you make in comments under an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
emp.data %>% mutate(realvalues = case_when((is.na(realvalues)|realvalues == '') & str_detect(emp_name,'^N.*') ~ 'N', TRUE ~ realvalues),
                     emp_name = str_remove(emp_name, 'N...\\s'))
  emp_id emp_name realvalues salary
1      1    M3737          N 623.30
2      2    M3738          N 515.20
3      3    M3739          N 611.00
4      4    M3740          N 729.00
5      5    M3741          N 843.25
```

Comment: how to do it without even mentioning column name "emp_name"

Comment: @kumar, didn't get your query, you mean modifying a column without using the column name?

Comment: how to get the same expected output without mentioning "emp_name" in the code